# Status 400 from WebApi when calling PostAsJsonAsync from Blazor Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, blazor, webapi

I am getting the following error when calling my Web Api

> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IMyDataService.LogicalHandler[101]
> End processing HTTP request after 70.5ms - 400

I am using **PostAsJsonAsync** and it's like it doesn't like the **TValue** object in the client.
When running from the client in debug mode, the break point in the Api controller in never hit and status 400 is instantly returned.

I have tested this by just sending a simple string and it works, it just doesn't work when using a model.

```
public async Task<MyModel> AddNew(MyModel model)
{
    var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/add-model", model, jsonSerializerOptions);
    
    // omitted for brevity
    return model;
}
```

This is confusing me because I have another API controller with a post request; in another component and it works perfectly fine.

The controller:

```
[HttpPost("add-model")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> AddNewModel(MyModel model)
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: What's in MyModel?  Try the following: 1. `public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> AddNewModel([FromBody]MyModel model)`.  2. setting the full route `[HttpPost("/api/add-model")]`.

Comment: I did try the frombody with a string example which worked but im assuming as im using an object the frombody isnt used (my other controller works that way). The full path shouldn't matter because the communication works using the string. But later i will try both and post the results.

Comment: one of the causes of 400 "bad request" is exceeding the post parameter limit.  If the model is very large, you might check that.

Comment: I had a theory whilst I was out and it looks like it is the reason. I was only populating some of the fields and i'm guessing the server didn't like what it was receiving. As a test I have populated every field and I get a status 200 back. I did have a load of fields in the model class setup to allow nulls so not sure why that is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because I was only populating some of the fields to send over to the API.
I tried a test to populate every field and send it over and it has worked and returned a status 200.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pass all fields , else make properties as nullable which you are not passing from class object.